# Is it possible to schedule automated tests via Microsoft Test Manager?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I'm trying to schedule automated coded UI tests.

I have created a test plan and associated it with a test case which is associated with an ordered test list. I know how to run tests, but is it possible to schedule the running of tests (e.g. on a daily basis using the latest available build).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test cases or test plans can be run [from command line using Tcm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff942469.aspx). A Powershell or DOS script could then be scheduled via Windows Task Scheduler to run these commands.

Answer (score 1):

We have a simular solution to our automated tests. (but not using the Microsoft Test Manager for sceduling)
Each build we are running the automated tests. It's a small program that has a `FileSystemWatcher` that are checking a file that changes everytime a build is succeded.
When the buld is completed, it downloads the new files and then starts MSTest with parameters.

If you have a orderedtest list you can always make a cmd / bat file to run MSTest with som parameters, and then scedule it using Task Sceduler in Windows : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243181(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243181%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Already doing this - but the problem with this approach is that I want to test on remote environments. To do this with coded UI tests, I need to maintain active connections via Remote Desktop. I've been told I don't need to do this when running tests via Microsoft Test Manager.

Answer (score 1):

You can also edit a build definition to only run the tests, and schedule a daily build at the desired time

Answer (score 0):

you can run them in TFS inside your build definitions , like build deploy test